# HANA SQLScript dbms_output.put_line() equivalent?

Tags: hana

Does HANA SQLScript have an equivalent function to `dbms_output.put_line()`? Looking for something that can be used to print an output like I do with PL/SQL or Python.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is nothing similar to that.
As the documentation shows in some of the example codings, you may enter trace text into a logging table.

- Lars

Comment: So you are talking about the TRACE section 8.3.3 in the latest SQLscript documentation? http://help.sap.com/hana/sap_hana_sql_script_reference_en.pdf

Comment: Nope, that's not it.
What I meant was: if you want to access logging output on SQLScript level , you need to build a logging table and insert the output in there. Later on you can select and read from the table to check the output.

Answer (score 1):

hana has built-in library SQLSCRIPT_PRINT.
For details see [SAP_HELP](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/dcf4bb06b8c540f3a28053784e2c6c16.html)

a sample code:

```
DO BEGIN
  USING SQLSCRIPT_PRINT as LIB;
  BEGIN
    LIB:PRINT_LINE('Hello World!');
  END;
END;
```